# Strange HTML-table issue, first row tag disappears

Tags: c#, html, forms, html-table

I'm having issues generating a HTML-table using C#. On each row I have a remove button used to remove that row from the database.

However it doesn't seem to work for the first row, I have identified the issue to be that the first row doesn't have a -tag around it, and I don't know why.

I'm using something like the following code to generate the table:

```
// Initalize SQL connection...
string resp = ""; // Response string, used to build the html

resp += "<table id='hor-minimalist-b' summary='Product list'>";

// Display the column names as headers
resp += "<thead><tr>";
resp += "<th scope='col'>Artikel</th>";
// Use empty headers for button columns
resp += "<th scope='col'></th>"; // Remove button
foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    resp += "<th scope='col'>" + dc.ColumnName + "</th>";
}
resp += "</tr></thead>";

// Display the data for each row. Loop through the rows first.
resp += "<tbody>";
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    resp += "<tr>";
    // Then loop through the columns for the current row print them
    string artID = getArticleID(dr); // Get the primary key for row
    for (i = 1; i <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        // Add additional buttons
        if (i == 2)
        {
            // Add remove button
            resp += "<td>";
                resp += "<form method='post' action='Default.aspx'>";
                    resp += "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='deleteRow' />";
                    resp += "<input type='hidden' name='rowID' value='" + artID + "' />";
                    resp += "<input type='submit' value='Ta bort' onclick=\"return confirm('Är du säker på att du vill ta bort artikel " + artID + "');\" />";
                resp +="</form>";
            resp +="</td>";
        }

        resp += "<td>" + dr[i - 1] + "</td>";
    }
    resp += "</tbody>";
    resp += "</table>";
}
```

The end results in something like the following HTML:

```
<table id="hor-minimalist-b" summary="Product list">
    -
    <thead>
        -
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    -
    <tbody>
        -
        <tr>
            <td id="val15462_0">
                15462
            </td>
            -
            <td>
                -
                <form method="post" action="Default.aspx">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="deleteRow" />
                <input type="hidden" name="rowID" value="15462" />
                <input type="submit" value="Ta bort" onclick="return confirm('Är du säker på att du vill ta bort artikel 15462');" />
                </form>
            </td>
            -
            <td>
                <input value="Ändra" type="button" onclick="editArt(15462)" />
            </td>
            <td id="val15462_1">
                AX-10.535
            </td>
            <td id="val15462_3">
                Detaljspecifikt värde A
            </td>
            <td id="val15462_4">
                Detaljspecifikt värde B
            </td>
            <td id="val15462_2">
                kitten2.jpeg
            </td>
        </tr>
        -
        <tr>
            <td id="val15463_0">
                15463
            </td>
            -
            <td>
                -
                <form method="post" action="Default.aspx">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="deleteRow" />
                <input type="hidden" name="rowID" value="15463" />
                <input type="submit" value="Ta bort" onclick="return confirm('Är du säker på att du vill ta bort artikel 15463');" />
                </form>
            </td>
            -
            <td>
                <input value="Ändra" type="button" onclick="editArt(15463)" />
            </td>
            <td id="val15463_1">
                AX-10.536
            </td>
            <td id="val15463_3">
                Detaljspecifikt värde A
            </td>
            <td id="val15463_4">
                Detaljspecifikt värde
            </td>
            <td id="val15463_2">
                kitten3.jpg
            </td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Notice how the first row doesn't have a form tag around it. And I'm really not sure what might be causing it.

**Update:**
I corrected the HTML above, it was not properly pasted. The one that is pasted now is the string returned from the server function building the HTML, which *does* contain the form tag (as seen from the XML visualizer in VS, so don't mind the -'s).

However when I use a browser to debug the website the form tag does not appear in the first data row like so:

```
<td>
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="deleteRow"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="rowID" value="15462"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Ta bort" onclick="return confirm('Är du säker på att du vill ta bort artikel 15462');"/>
</td>
```

Which messes up other parts of my site since there are wild inputs presents

Thanks for your time, I'd appreciate any suggestions at all!

Comment: As an aside: In your code above you have a TD inside another TD - that isn't valid code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, It was just a bad paste from the browser =)

Comment: `Notice how the first row doesn't have a form tag around it. And I'm really not sure what might be causing it.` :- if what you are trying to do is wrap a `<form>` tag around a `<tr>` tag, then it's not possible, as tables can only have `<tr>`'s and `<td>`'s , all other tags shall be inside in a `<td>` tag.

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha, I'm trying to use a form tag inside the <td>. Which should be able to hold it. Otherwise, how would i submit POST-data for my delete button?

Comment: @ChewToy If you plan to use JavaScript , i would suggest that you put all the form in a different part of the page other than tables, and let the delete buttons trigger a function which would in turn select the desired form and submit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using JS to submit a hidden form on other parts of the page instead of including a form inside the table.